# What will System.getProperty("user.name") print if there is no user login

Tags: java, linux

I am having a cronjob that calls a java program to check on active login user.
The cronjob will run in every 5 minutes.
What will System.getProperty("user.name") print if nobody login when the cronjob runs?

I am currently running the cronjob inside my VM.
I disconnect from putty & winscp but the cron.log print the output as "root"

localhost CROND[14539]: (root) CMDOUT (Login user is :: root)

Comment: The cronjob will need to run using a user in any case, "root" in your case. It won't be able to check whether another user logged in by itself - you'd need to query the OS for active sessions.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.name")` will print the username of the user who started the program/ cronjob. "root" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The cron job prints `root` because it runs as the root user no matter who is logged in. It runs as root because it was created as root. If you want to run the cronjob as another user you can use one of these approches:

Add the user you want to allow to run cron, into the `/etc/cron.allow` file. Simply add the username on a line of its own. Then add the cronjob when you are logged in as that user.

If you still runs the job as root you can run the job as a specific user:

```
1 2 * * * su username -c "/path/to/my/scriptfile.sh"
1 2 * * * sudo -u username "/path/to/my/scriptfile.sh"
```

The first uses the `su` command and the other the `sudo` command.